# Postback causing all dropdownlist selecteditems to reset in GridView asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

**My problem**

On `RowDataBound`, I have programmatically added dropdownlists to every cell in a GridView. Each dropdownlist is populated with the same `DataSource`.

When the program is running, the user will select different items from the dropdownlists, and then press the 'Save' button. At this point, I am meant to retrieve the `selecteditem` for every dropdownlist in the GridView and save it back to a database.

However, when I attempted to use the `FindControl()` method on the GridView and find the dropdownlists to get the `selecteditems` from each of them, there was none to be found. I realised that maybe due to postback the dropdonwlists are getting removed, as they were added programmatically on `RowDataBound`.

To work around this, I saved the GridView to `Cache` after adding in the dropdownlists on `RowDataBound` and then re-populated the gridview again on button click with all the controls etc...

Only then did I realise that obviously because I was repopulating the dropdowns, that any `selecteditem` chosen at runtime was getting wiped...

**My questions**

Is there a way to not get rid of all my controls on `PostBack`?

AND/OR

Is there a way to somehow store all the `selecteditems` chosen at runtime before the 'Save' button is clicked?

**Code for assistance**

```
protected void gv_Rota_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int day = e.Row.RowIndex;
                day += 1;
                ddlShift = new DropDownList();
                ddlShift.ID = "ddlShift" + "WK" + i.ToString() + "DAY" + day.ToString();
                ddlShift.DataSource = DCListOfShifts;
                ddlShift.DataValueField = "SHIFT_ID";
                ddlShift.DataTextField = "SHIFT_NAME";
                ddlShift.Attributes.Add("Place", i.ToString());
                ddlShift.DataBind();
                ddlShift.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Shift..."));
                ddlShift.CssClass = "ddl_rotamanager";
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddlShift);
            }
        }

        Cache.Add("cacheGridView", gv_Rota, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0), CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
    }
```

Comment: 2 ways to do this, store hidden runat=server fields and set their value via js / jquery.  Other way is to recreate the controls on postback.

Comment: @JonH Thank you for your response. However, I want the user to select values from the dropdownlist, not have pre-set values? Unless you meant set the values when selectionchanged is called, and then with the same point, if I recreated the controls on postback, I wouldn't receive any selected items still?